# Where does the spell checking function comes from?

Tags: spell-check

1. I am using Firefox. Whenever I type
   my questions on Stack Exchange
   sites, there will be automatic spell
   checking.

   Does this function comes
   from Firefox, or from Stack Exchange
   sites, or somewhere else?
2. If it comes form Firefox, why is
   there no spell checking when I type
   in some other websites?

   Just off
   your head, in what cases, will there will
   be spell checking and in what cases not?
3. American English and British English
   may spell some words in different
   ways. For example, if I type
   "optimization", it will be
   automatically underscored to let me
   know the spelling is wrong.

   How can
   I make the spell checking tool to
   recognize American English spelling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As I type this answer on webapps.stackexchange.com, Firefox is providing the spell checking.
2. It depends on the website. I suspect that any site that uses standard `textarea` tags will allow Firefox to spell-check it. Google Docs, on the other hand, uses its own custom spell checker.
3. Right-click a misspelled word. Select "Languages" and make sure "English / United States" is selected. If you don't see it there, select "Add Dictionaries..." and install the "English (US)" dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

When ever a user type, a spell check program runs behind the scene, and it try's to match with the its local dictionary, if the user entered word is not in its dictionary then the word will be highlighted with the red line, and if you right click that word, you will get an possible combination of its closest matching word. Say for example, if you have typed **teh** then you will get the possible combination as **the**.

In short words, a spell check program runs behind the scene that makes us comfortable:) And i guess it depends on the site, which enables this option:)